# LTSpice, plot a current–voltage characteristic

Tags: ltspice, ngspice, plot, device-characteristics

I have LTSpice on macOS.

I would like to plot in x-axis the voltage `v(2)` and in y-axis the current `I(R1)`.
But, when I add traces to the plot pane, I cannot choose the axis. How can I plot the current–voltage characteristic?

In ngSpice the command is: `plot (v(1)-v(2))/1000 vs v(2) xlimit -7 2`. I don't know how to *translate* this on LTSpice.

Comment: Are you doing a .DC sweep or a .tran simulation?

Answer (score 2):

Plot `I(R1)` normally, then move the mouse cursor over the x-axis, until it turns into a ruler, right-click on it, then write `v(2)` instead of `time`. To get back to `time`, simply delete whatever expression there is instead of `time` and click OK.

Judging by the frequency and topics of the questions you posted, I'd rather suggest you to try and read the manual. [The LTwiki](http://ltwiki.org/?title=Main_Page) might complement with some little hidden treasures. But it's best if you try to get to know the tool with which you're about to spend time with, rather than stop at every step and wait for answers online. Nobody says you have to know it perfectly, but enough to know how to work with it, without getting frustrated that you cannot continue because of something trivial.

Comment: I'd trade my first born child to be able to upvote that second paragraph 824 times.

Comment: @SteKulov I find it common sense, and not just about LTspice -- any tool that you're about to spend time using is worth taking a little bit of time to know it better. Even if that "little bit" means just enough for whatever time usage you had in mind.